# calculate days in a month with year and month number?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

Instead of using:

```
int noOfDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
```

I want to use the 2 values passed in to get number of days in a month:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? month, int? year)
{
    DateTime Month = System.Convert.ToDateTime(month);
    DateTime Year = System.Convert.ToDateTime(year);
    int noOfDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month);
```

(Year, Month) is flagging as invalid arguments? any ideas? maybe system.conert.todatetime.month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are `DateTime` variables but [`DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) needs `int`s:

```
int noOfDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year.Value, month.Value);
```

If they can be null:

```
int noOfDaysInMonth = -1;
if(year != null && month != null)
    noOfDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year.Value, month.Value);
```

Comment: What if those are null?

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload for the `DateTime.DaysInMonth` method that takes two `DateTime` instances. Instead of creating those two `DateTime` instances, just pass the parameters you received directly to `DaysInMonth`.

Notice that method **can't take null values**, so either drop the nullables or sanitize your input, i.e.: check if the year and month are null, and if they are, use some default value instead.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.DaysInMonth takes int parameter and not date time parameter

```
public static int DaysInMonth(
    int year,
    int month
)
```

Beware though, you are passing in nullable int's. So check before if they have value

```
if(month.HasValue && year.HasValue)
{
   var numOfDays = DaysInMonth(year.Value, month.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any `DateTime` object here, but you *need* to validate the input!

```
public ActionResult Index(int? month, int? year)
{
    int noOfDaysInMonth = -1;

    if(year.HasValue && year.Value > 0 && 
            month.HasValue && month.Value > 0 && month.Value <=12)
    {
        noOfDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year.Value, month.Value);
    } 
    else
    {
        // parameters weren't there or they had wrong values
        // i.e. month = 15 or year = -5 ... nope!

        noOfDaysInMonth = -1; // not as redundant as it seems...
    }

    // rest of code.
}
```

The `if` works because conditions are evaluated from left to right.